# basic shell implementation - open: permission denied

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to implement a basic shell in c, and this is how I redirect, where "storage" is what I want to write to the file specified in "directory":

```
void execute_redirect(char* directory, char* storage) {
    int file;
    int pid;
    char* args[2];
    int status;
    args[0] = storage;
    args[1] = NULL;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("%s", directory);
        file = open(directory, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (file < 0) {
            perror("open");
        }
        dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(file);
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            perror("execvp");
        }
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

However when I run this I get open: Permission denied, although when I printf directory it prints exactly what I want.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `directory`? Is it really a "directory" or is it a file path?

Comment: @kaylum if I type /out.txt, is that correct? My intention is to make out.txt in the current directory.

Comment: No, doesn't look correct. That will attempt to create a file in the root `/` directory which is usually only writable with superuser access. Try just `out.txt`.

Comment: Then I'm getting "execvp: No such file or directory." Shouldn't it create the file in the directory?

Comment: Well, what is the value of `storage`? Do you know what `execvp` does and what its parameter values need to be?

Comment: Actually, not entirely, I'll look that up. But you solved my initial question, so thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why is the child process calling `wait` if `execvp` fails? Typically you would call `_exit` at that point, and leave any waiting to the parent process.

Comment: Yep it wasn't working before...thanks for the tip @HAL9000.